# .DS_Store creation disabled on network shares, but I want them enabled for a specific share

Tags: macos, network, finder, time-capsule

I use my Mac in a corporate Windows environment all the time, and have it set so that it doesn't drop .DS_Store turds all over the network.  I used the following well-known terminal command to disable it:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

However, I also have a server at home as well as a Time Capsule, and I would like the .DS_Store file created on those shares.

Is there any way to make an exception to the rule?

I'm running Mavericks BTW.

Comment: *How* have you set it? App or Terminal command?

Comment: Using the terminal: `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have it both ways.

I can imagine a bit of a work around that involves the Mac knowing what network it is on, and then changing the defaults write command to match the network.
Something like http://www.controlplaneapp.com/about/ would help you get that done.

(not the simplest solution I'll admit)